# In werewolv.es, does the Bloodthirster give the wolfpack an extra kill the night immediately following the lynch of the Bloodthirster?

Tags: werewolv.es

Does the Bloodthirster give the wolfpack an extra kill the night immediately following the lynch of the Bloodthirster, provided that the wolfpack still has more than four wolves still remaining?

The [how to play](https://werewolv.es/guides/roles/Bloodthirster) for this role states:

> Each night that the Bloodthirster is alive and there are more than 4 members of the Wolfpack alive, the Wolfpack gains an extra kill.

So it would seem that the ability should not trigger following the Bloodthirster's lynch. However, since lynches are often considered to happen after nightfall, it isn't clear whether the ability is lost after morning breaks.